# How to send a cross-domain ajax request with cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cookies, saas

I'm developing a SaaS application, users create account and login in my SaaS system. Then, the SaaS application has a JS code that customers should include this JS code in their websites, and inside the code I need to send a `POST` Ajax Request to my SaaS domain (it's a cross-domain request).

The problem is that in order to share the credential of logged-in users, I have to set `withCredentials` property and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true`.

I'm not sure whether this is a good approach or not? Maybe I should use another approach like using OAuth or something to share the logged-in users credential...

I will appreciate any advices.

Comment: 1) How are your user logged in? Via cookies (thats what your title suggests) or `Authentication` headers (aka htaccess - what I understand the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is for). 
2) Does your current approach work or not?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be using JSONP as your type:

```
$.ajax(
{ 
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://test.com/api/getlist.json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
  },
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", "session=xxxyyyzzz");
  },
  success: function(){
       alert('success');
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
  }
}
);
```

Comment: `JSONP` and `POST` verb? Do you think it's possible?

Answer (score -1):

To enable cross domain requests with credentials, your server should support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). With CORS enabled your client code can add the `withCredentials` set to `true` to include cookies in the requests.

Comment: I've said already that I know what `withCredentils` does. I need another solution...